# PHP: How to prevent user go to login page when the user click back button after logged in?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Basically, i dont want the user accessibly to the login page by clicking back button after he/she successfully login to the system.

Below us the code of login check.php:-

```
<?php


include 'database.php'; 
session_start();                                            

if (isset ($_POST['namaPengguna']))
{                   
$kataLaluan = $_POST['kataLaluan'];
$namaPengguna = $_POST['namaPengguna'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM pengguna 
        WHERE namaPengguna='$namaPengguna' && kataLaluan = '$kataLaluan' ";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);
$row = $result->num_rows; 
$info = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
$_SESSION['PenggunanoKP']=$info['PenggunanoKP'];

    if($row<1)  
    {
       header("Location:login design.php");
    }
    else{
         header("Location:pilihAction.php");
    }

}

?>
```

The next page :

```
<?php include 'database.php';
include 'session.php'; 
?>


<?php

echo $_SESSION['PenggunanoKP'];
?>
/*html code
```

Comment: 1) Set a flag in $_SESSION[]  when user login; clear the flag when user logout.  

2) Create a function to check if this flag is set.  

3) Create a new .php file to call this function only and it will return true or false.  

4) Include this .php file in all of your pages which requires user login. 

5) If this function returns false, user is required to login again, use php header function to redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: You can one just set the session_destroy function login page like if login session is avaliable then destroy the session. It will load every time when you open. the login page.

Comment: @CKWong sorry if i'm asking because i'm a bit new in php. So, how to set the flag in  $_SESSION[]  And... what is flag actually? Huhu

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code. Have a read of the use of prepared statements. Also passwords should ***NEVER** be stored in plain text form. They should ***ALWAYS*** be stored in a ***hashed*** form. Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php for info on PHP's methods for dealing with password hashing

Answer (score 0):

Your Welcome Page (after login) should look like this

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['directaccess']))
  {
    if(isset($_POST['logoutbtn']))
    {
        session_destroy();
        header("location: loginform.php");
    }
  /* Your code goes here */

  }
  else{
     exit('Access denied');
   }
  ?>

 <form class="myform" action="" method="post">  
 <input name="logoutbtn" type="submit" value="logout" class="sbbtn" 
  id="logout_btn" class="test"/>
 </form>
  </div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

`Explanation :`
On your Main Login/check-in page : 
Set a flag in $_SESSION `(in my example its $_SESSION['directaccess'])` just before calling header function (to successful login Welcome page).
.
Then on your success Welcome Page, use the code snippet above. Check if that flag is set then only give access to your Page code else `exit('Access Denied')`.

Logout button `action` should be on the same Welcome page. If button is clicked, destroy session and then call header function back to Main Login/check-in page.

Comment: sorry @AjitRaghav if i'm asking because i'm a bit new in php. So, how to set the flag in my main login page? And... what is flag actually? Huhu

Comment: @HasifahHassan On your main login page, where you are verifying username and password, if they match, then set `$_SESSION['directaccess']) = 1 ;` . On this page you must have `session_start();` in the beginning of your code. Psss .... If still need help, copy paste your Main Login page and Welcome page code here.

Comment: Okay then, @AjitRaghav so, the above code is the main login page and here i will attached the next page of login... thanks anywayy, :)

Comment: @HasifahHassan Hope my code helped :) . Just set `$_SESSION['directaccess']) = 1` in case of user/password match before `header()`. On next page copy my code with change in `header("location: loginform.php");` Give your own location and you can set flag name to  anything. Vote Up if that helped, in case somebody else needs it :) Cheers

Comment: Sorry, @AjitRaghav, i'm still can go back to my login page... :(

Comment: @HasifahHassan Paste your both files in question and we'll see :)

Comment: i already editted my question. And basically the html code is just to display table and other link button such as logout button, home button, and etc